# Customize scanner camera view zbar ios sdk

Tags: zbar-sdk, camera-view

Is there a way to customize zbar sdk  camera view.
I used below code to add the scanner.

```
ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
reader.readerDelegate = self;
reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMaskAll;

ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
[scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
               config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                   to: 0];
 [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I wanted to do like this kind of screen. [link](http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple2/v4/77/e6/3c/77e63c5b-53fa-df78-9208-1c690bdc7d2f/screen568x568.jpeg)